# Remove .php and .html extensions AND have directories with same name?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to remove the .php and .html extensions of my website pages in the browser. I found this code online to add in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
```

However, if a have a php file named "home.php" and at the same time a directory named "home" this doesn't work anymore. I think I might have to add something like

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
```

but I like this it does not work either.
So how can I achieve this?

Comment: So if you call `yourdomain.com/home` what is supposed to be requested - `home.php` script or `home` directory? What exactly you want to achieve? What if you have `home.php` as directory name or `home` as script name with no extension? You must think off all scenarios.

Comment: So calling `domain.com/home` should display `home.php`. Then I want to have a folder called `home` with other php files in it, e.g. `about.php`, such that I can call `about.php` via `domain.com/home/about`. Can I achieve this using the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Remove the `!-d` rule.

Comment: That looks like a pretty good beginning of tons of problems...

Comment: Why not just rename `home.php` into `home/index.php`, and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be able to give a priority to file when it request comes without `/` with same name with directory as well as removing both `php & html` and determine which one to check first like this :

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(php|html)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```

So , by the code above , extensions will be removed then will check first if there is php file match this , then html and finally if there is a directory .

So , the request for `/home` only will check first a php that named home if it is exist ok , then directory home but the request `/home/about` will go directly to about inside home directory.

Clear browser cache then test it , if it is Ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this simple code in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**Update:**
As @Niet mentioned I missed condition so add this line before rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

Comment: This is actually worse than the code in the question, since this won't even check if the file exists before trying to rewrite to it.

Comment: Adding RewriteCond as `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` will do the trick.